# Does it make sense to have static variable in constructor?

Tags: java

In the following code, while the PropertyValue is constructed, the two static sets are populated. Does this way make sense?

```
class PropertyValue{

    String cid;
    String property;
    String value;

    public static Set<String> properties = new HashSet<>();
    public static Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();

    public PropertyValue(String cid, String property, String value) {
        this.cid = cid;
        this.property = property;
        this.value = value;

        properties.add(property);
        values.add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it does not.  But separately, having mutable static variables of any kind is usually an antipattern.

Comment: Much better to let whatever client code is interested in these values handle indexing.

Comment: Does not this work like a static counter?

Comment: *Does this way make sense?* It's impossible to say without knowing the entire design.  Note, though, that the code as posted is [not multithread-safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html): "Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash set concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the set, it must be synchronized externally."

Comment: @martin: who told you static counters are a good idea? :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a kind of key value pair cache design, but non thread safe.

and why two sets in place of a Map ?

You could make a threadsafe singleton with a singleton holder and a Hashtable

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

public class Properties
{
    private Map<String,String> properties = new Hashtable<>();

    private Properties(){}

    private static class PropertiesHolder{
        private final static Properties instance = new Properties();
    }

    public static Properties getInstance(){
        return PropertiesHolder.instance;
    }

    public void put(String property, String value){
        properties.put(property, value);
    }

    public void get(String property){
        properties.get(property);
    }
}
```

and to use

```
    Properties properties = Properties.getInstance();
    properties.put("foo","bar");
    properties.get("foo");
```

With your class

```
class PropertyValue{

    String cid;
    String property;
    String value;

    public PropertyValue(String cid, String property, String value) {
        this.cid = cid;
        this.property = property;
        this.value = value;

        Properties properties = Properties.getInstance();
        properties.put(property, value);
    }
}
```

But I think it's not the responsability of the PropertyValue class to maintain this key value "store"
This store should be populated after (or before) a new PropertyValue instance but not in the constructor.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

You can keep your two sets of string if you don't need to store the properties and values by pair, or directly store a Set of PropertyValue in the singleton

Comment: That completely changes the behavior of the posted code - separate and independent sets of two values, presumably to simply keep a set of every separate value encountered. (And that's an assumption on my part)  Using a `Map<>` as you've posted changes the entire meaning of the code from merely tracking what's been encountered to mapping two values together in ways that might not make sense. You're assuming that is what the OP needs. And what does *a static field is unique by thread* mean?  Your implementation isn't thread-safe either - it's concurrent modification of the *same* HashMap<>.

Comment: Ok, it's true i change a lot the code to help maybe it's not a good idea  but i think it thread safe (cf my link  : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) and it's not difficult to adapt this code to preserve the two sets

Comment: you right it wasn't thread safe because HashMap is not syncronized, my bad. it's corrected by the use of a Hashtable which is syncronized

Answer (score 1):

The only time you should be making a member variable static is if you don't want the life of the members tied to the life of the object. Maybe you have a counter that is shared between objects that are created or destroyed. Or maybe you have a function that needs to persist before the object is instantiated or created. Maybe you have a base class with a static member that is shared by child classes. Those are the only times I generally make a member static.

In your example it is hard to tell, because without knowing the full scope of how the class is being implemented it is really hard to tell if it makes sense or not.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from whether the static Set's are a good idea...

The code should be placed in a static initializer. This ensures that the static content is ready when the class is loaded. Depending on the class design, it's possible that the constructor would never be called.

```
static {
    // do the work
}
```

Comment: *The code should be placed in a static initializer.*  No. `public static Set<String> properties = new HashSet<>();` doesn't need to be in a `static {}` block.  Static initialization is  done the same as a `static {}` block.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the design goes...

Public fields, in this case the Set's, are generally a bad idea. If other classes need to access the Set's, they should do so through static methods.

Static Set's and Map's make sense in cases where configuration information is used by all the instances of the class. However, the instances, typically, should not be allowed to modify the content. As I noted in my previous answer, a static initializer should be used to load the Set's or Map's.